# How To Convert the rest of An Binary To A String in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a binary and i use patter matching for resolve the first one  EJ:

```
<<code:: binary-size(2), _::binary-size(1), rest::binary>> = line
```

the rest variable still in binary format, i want it in string formatt?

Comment: What do you mean "string format"? Strings are Binaries in Elixir. Can you give an example value of `line` and current and expected output?

Comment: for example when i print rest, the value still the binary that was readed from a file, and the code variable was converted and the rest of the binary not

Comment: An example here: {"SP", <<57, 56, 52, 52, 49, 48, 68, 48, 66, 49, 83, 67, 73, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 51, 51, 51, 52, 57, 51, 52, 53, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 50, 48, 49, 54, 49, 50, 51, 49, 32, ...>>}

Comment: What does the i command in iex tell you about rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of representation. Turns out, IEx console was unable to display the data with chars and it printed it out as codepoints. That usually happens when the binary contains e.g. `\0` char.

Look, let’s take the very beginning or what you have:

```
iex> <<57, 56, 52, 52, 49, 48, 68, 48, 66, 49, 83, 67, 73, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 49>>
#⇒ "984410D0B1SCI       1"
```

Now let’s put zero byte there:

```
iex> <<57, 0, 52>>
#⇒ <<57, 0, 52>>
```

There could be even more surprising representation glitches:

```
iex> [7, 8, 9, 10]
#⇒ '\a\b\t\n'
```

Now IEx sees the char list and it prints it out as a char list. `'\a'` is `7`, `'\b'` is 8 etc.